# Why do the three admirals of One Piece Akainu, Aokiji and Kizaru have different(opposite) power from their character?

Tags: one-piece

I have been watching the anime and reading the manga of One Piece for 2 years and I found out some strange and good things.

One of the things I found out recently is that all three Admirals have different(opposite) powers from their behaviour.

- Akainu has the power of magama but is cold hearted
- Aokiji has the power of ice but is warm hearted
- Kizaru has the power of the speed of light but is a slow talker

Is there any back story on these traits?

Comment: Are you asking why their powers are opposed to their personality ?

Comment: I don't think that this has an actual cannonical answer. It's a design choice by their creator. The world of one piece is filled with humor like that. Oda is working on a high school comedy in secret

Comment: Funfact: Fujitoras power is purple because his personality is a mixture of Akainu and Aokiji. (can't find the source right now)

Comment: I don't even think the power DF can change the personality of the user.

Comment: Callat, can I get a source on Oda's secret side project?

Answer (score 1):

While this exactly is not stated from Oda himself, Oda really likes that kind of humor. It is stated though that the second part of their name for example: Aka-Inu
*Inu* is Japanese for dog.

They stem from an old story of [Momotaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momotar%C5%8D), where a boy from heaven came down in a peach (his name means peach as well).
The boy was accompanied by the animals. Thus the names.

In the FPS for chapter 558 Oda also states why they look like they do.
He got the inspiration from famous Japanese movie actors.

[Bunta_Sugawara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunta_Sugawara) - Akainu Movie: "Machinegun Dragon"

[saku_Matsuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%ABsaku_Matsuda) - Aokiji Movie: "Tantei Monogatari"

[Kunie_Tanaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunie_Tanaka) - Kizaru Movie: "Truck Yarou" from 1978

[Shintaro_Katsu](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shintar%C5%8D_Katsu) - Fujitora Movie: "Zatōichi"

Comment: This isn't asking about the names but rather about their powers being opposite from their behavior. Other than your first sentence, it's not clear how this question answers that.